# Matrix transformation - rotate about object origin

Tags: math, matrix, 3d

With the following Code i move a object along the x axis, and rotate it relative to its position every frame.

```
quad.getModel().setIdentity();
quad.getModel().scale(new Vector3f(10, 10, 10));
quad.getModel().translate(new Vector3f(x, 0, 0));
quad.getModel().rotate(x * 2, new Vector3f(0, 1f, 0f));
```

Now i want to remove the `model.setIdentity()`. How i can achieve the same thing now?

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to rotate all objects by their own centers and then translate them to the real position (it isn't working)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25974144/how-to-rotate-all-objects-by-their-own-centers-and-then-translate-them-to-the-re)

Answer (score 0):

Okay, i figured out the solution my self.
I just had to rotate it back every frame, then move it, than rotate it back.
The reason is, that rotation changes the object-relative axis. So translating
also moves along this new axis. Moving along the origin, or, the "old" axis, 
just needs to reset the rotation before that.