# Rotate object to "look at" another object in 3 dimensions?

Tags: c++, math, matrix, 3d, rotation

I want to create a formula that rotates my object (o1) to always point into the direction of another object (o2), regardless of  o1's position.

Kind of like the camera in the following image:
http://puu.sh/bLUWw/aaa653accf.png

I got the following code so far, but the yaw-axis seems to be inverted:

```
Vector3 lookat = { lookAtPosition.x, lookAtPosition.y, lookAtPosition.z };
Vector3 pos = { position.x, position.y, position.z };
Vector3 objectUpVector = { 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f };

Vector3 zaxis = Vector3::normalize(lookat - pos);
Vector3 xaxis = Vector3::normalize(Vector3::cross(objectUpVector, zaxis));
Vector3 yaxis = Vector3::cross(zaxis, xaxis);

Matrix16 pm = {
    xaxis.x, yaxis.x, zaxis.x, 0,
    xaxis.y, yaxis.y, zaxis.y, 0,
    xaxis.z, yaxis.z, zaxis.z, 0,
    0, 0, 0, 1
};
```

See the following image:
http://puu.sh/bLUSG/5228bb2176.jpg

I'm sure it's just a few variables that have to be swapped, but I couldn't find them...

PS: The position of the object matrix is multiplied at a later stage, for testing purposes...

Comment: Does the world have a positive y axis going downwards, rather than up, in which case, the objectUpVector would be {0.0, -1.0, 0.0 }

Comment: Hasn't this been answered in [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/349050/calculating-a-lookat-matrix?rq=1)?

Comment: @Merlin069 If I do that the Teapot will be upside-down but it will rotate in the desired direction.

Comment: @Surt That answer goes for a view matrix, which is inverted as far as I know... I don't want it to be inverted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the answer to my issue, it turns out that I just had to change the order of the values inside the matrix like so:

```
Matrix16 pm = {
    xaxis.x, xaxis.y, xaxis.z, 0,
    yaxis.x, yaxis.y, yaxis.z, 0,
    zaxis.x, zaxis.y, zaxis.z, 0,
    0, 0, 0, 1
};
```

Comment: just need to add Column-wise matrices are for OpenGL (they choose it for some performance reason unknown to me) this is row-wise representation of matrix

Answer (score 1):

camera matrix is inverse of transform matrix representing its coordinate system

- look here: [Transform matrix anatomy](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25216549/2521214)
- origin = o1.position
- Z axis = o1.position-o2.position

  - and make it unit length of coarse
  - mine frustrum/Zbuffer are configured to view in -Z axis direction
- now just compute X,Y axises as perpendicular to eachother and Z also via crossproduct

  - and make them unit length of coarse
  - so take some vector (non parallel to Z)
  - ideally something best to align to like Up vector (0,1,0);
  - multiply it by Z axis and store result to X(or Y)
  - and then multiply it again by Z axis and store to Y(or X).
- Now you have the transform matrix M1 representing O1 coordinate system
- if you want just to render the object then thi is it
- if you want to have camera on object o1
- then just compute:
- `ViewMatrix=inverse(M1)*ProjectionMatrix;`
- here [inverse matrix computation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18041433/2521214) for mine OpenGL matrices

Comment: You are talking about a camera/view matrix here, that's not what I am trying to achieve however. I am only trying to rotate a single object (teapot/o1) to face in the direction of another object (sphere/o2)

Comment: @ManIkWeet in that case ignore last 4 lines of the answer of mine